# Updating selected datagrid view row - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-update

I have been building my dad a payroll/accounting program to save him the time and hustle of using Excel, might as well just go back to pen and paper. I got everything ready and in a primitive way is raw but user-friendly, but still can't seem to get the "update query" correct. I do have an Azure account which I'm currently using for "Cloud Database" access.

I have tried several ways:

```
//This is not the complete codes I have used.
newDataRow.Cells[0].Value = regYTD.Text;
string query = "UPDATE employeeInfo SET..."
/////////////////////////////////////////////

private void stubDbBtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
      //This is what I am currently using. 
      con.Open(); 
      string query = "UPDATE EmployeeInfo SET [Address Line 1] = '" + employeeAddress1.Text + "', [Address Line 2] = '" + employeeAddress2.Text + "', [City] = '" + employeeCity.Text + "', " +
                       "[State] = '" + employeeState.Text + "', [Zip] = '" + employeeZip.Text + "', [Phone] = '" + employeePhone.Text + "', " +
                       "[SSN] = '" + employeeSSN.Text + "', [Regular Earnings-YTD] = '" + regYTD.Text + "', " +
                       "[Overtime Earnings-YTD] = '" + ovrYTD.Text + "', [Total Earnings-YTD] = '" + totYTD.Text + "', [Federal-YTD] = '" + fedYTD.Text + "', " +
                       "[State-YTD] = '" + stYTD.Text + "', [Social-YTD] = '" + ssYTD.Text + "', [MediCare-YTD] = '" + medCareYTD.Text + "', " +
                       "[Total Deductions-YTD] = '" + deduYTD.Text + "',[Net Pay-YTD] = '" + netYTD.Text + "' ";
      SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
      dataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
 }
```

So far they have not given me an error either saying incorrect syntax or incorrect input, but using the `newDataRow.Cell` updates the desired cells locally only. This code updates correctly (up to the cloud) but it also updates the rest of the cells with the same `[Name]`.

Comment: Why are you injecting all of your values? Before anything you **need** to parametrise that query (using `Parameters.Add`). That statement is a SQL Injection nightmare.

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause on the query to update the row for the chosen primary key.  You are also using a select command to do an update. [Take a look at this sample application](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid) that will show you how to do this with ADO.Net.

Comment: Just a Suggestion try using parameterized queries [Why prefer Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements). And also as @Crowcoder suggested always have a `Where` clause assigned to your `Update` query or else it will be **Complete Table Update**.